# Cannot get array from JSON using getJSONArray

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I'm developing an android application which takes a json and gets an array of channels to streming from. Json is generated by this very simple php script.

```
<?php

$channels = [
'channels' => [
        'tele5' => 'http://mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM/cn/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8',
        'divinity' => 'http://mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B/cn/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8',
        'bemad' => 'http://mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B/cn/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8',
        'antena3' => 'http://a3live-lh.akamaihd.net/i/antena3_1@35248/master.m3u8'
        ]
];

echo json_encode($channels);
```

This script send a, I think, correct json string

```
{
    "channels":{
        "tele5":"http:\/\/mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM\/cn\/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8",
        "divinity":"http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8",
        "bemad":"http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8",
        "antena3":"http:\/\/a3live-lh.akamaihd.net\/i\/antena3_1@35248\/master.m3u8"
    }
}
```

I load the json and try to get and array with this snippet

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

    channels = json.getJSONArray("channels");
    for (int i = 0; i < channels.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject channel = channels.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = channel.getString("name");
        String url = channel.getString("url");
        Channel ch = new Channel(name, url);
        result.add(ch);
    }
```

But function getJSONArray throws the error

```
Value {"tele5":"http:\/\/mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM\/cn\/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8","divinity":"http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8","bemad":"http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8","antena3":"http:\/\/a3live-lh.akamaihd.net\/i\/antena3_1@35248\/master.m3u8"} at channels of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I've been trying to change my original php array to be able to parse the json string but with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I though, maybe the problem is the php array not well formed to be encoded as a json array.

Comment: That's true, it's actually not a json array. It's an object with other objects in it.

Comment: That's why I tagged it as PHP question. How my php array should look like in order to get a json array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks like you want a list of objects with `name` and `url` (which actually makes more sense).

Change the PHP to match that format:

```
$channels = [
    'channels' => [
        [
            'name' => 'tele5',
            'url'  => 'http://mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM/cn/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8'
        ],

        [
            'name' => 'divinity',
            'url'  => 'http://mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B/cn/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8'
        ],

        ... and so on
    ]
];

echo json_encode($channels);
```

This would give you json looking like this:

```
{
    "channels":[
        {
            "name": "tele5",
            "url": "http:\/\/mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM\/cn\/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8"
        },
        {
            "name": "divinity",
            "url": "http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8"
        },

        ... and so on
    ]
}
```

As others have pointed out, as soon as you have `"key" => "value"`, it will no longer be a json array, but a json object.

Comment: That's it. I made this code a while ago and forgot how I did it. A very big thank you @YvesLeBorg

Comment: @Dhouard If it solved the issue, feel free to accept the answer so others know that the issue have been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

`channels` is `JSONObject` (`"channels":{...}`) not `JSONOArray` (`[]`) so

```
JSONObject channels = json.getJSONObject("channels");
```

Update : to get json array use a `channel` index and `array()` function

```
<?php
  $channels['channels'] = array([
        'tele5' => 'http://mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM/cn/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8',
        'divinity' => 'http://mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B/cn/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8',
        'bemad' => 'http://mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com/out/u/3vkkbgnvsm2r5/104951/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B/cn/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8',
        'antena3' => 'http://a3live-lh.akamaihd.net/i/antena3_1@35248/master.m3u8'

]);

echo json_encode($channels);
```

and java code should be

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

channels = json.getJSONArray("channels");
for (int i = 0; i < channels.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject channel = channels.getJSONObject(i);
    String tele5 = channel.getString("tele5");
    String bemad = channel.getString("bemad");
    // use appropriate keys
}
```

Comment: Forgot to say that Channels is an JSONArray, so I need to be getJSONArray.

Comment: @Dhouard one thing that is weird , there is no `name` and `url`  in your data which you are trying to parse in java so it should be `tele5` or similar keys

Answer (score 2):

A JSONObject is something surrounded by `{...}`. A JSONArray is something surrounded by `[....]`. So `{"key": "value", "key2": "value2"}` is a JSONObject with 2 keys whereas 
`[1, 2, 3]` 
&

```
[{"key1" : "value1-1", "key2": "value2-1"},
 {"key1":  "value1-2", "key2": "value2-2"}, 
 {"key3",  "value3",   "key4": "value4"}]
```

are JSONArray. **The second JSONArray is very interesting and says a lot.** It is an array of 3 JSONObjects. the key and value can follow any convention you like.

Your script is sending a JSONObject with a key "channels" and a value which is another JSONObject.
In java, you are parsing the channels object correctly from response. But you are trying to get a JSONArray from channels which is incorrect.

Either update your script output **(Notice the [])** :

```
{
    "channels":[{
        "tele5":"http:\/\/mset-prod-1.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/RsZXlnNTE6re1fFuFEI0UrdA2Uj7pNGM\/cn\/5d62490854b545598f64eaa84709400b_4.m3u8",
        "divinity":"http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8",
        "bemad":"http:\/\/mset-prgb-2.live-delivery.ooyala.com\/out\/u\/3vkkbgnvsm2r5\/104951\/IybDNyYTE6j7PZaKerX9iKFSCuctjf5B\/cn\/95d3fccb2d6f4ad6b09d23e7c67d3acf_4.m3u8",
        "antena3":"http:\/\/a3live-lh.akamaihd.net\/i\/antena3_1@35248\/master.m3u8"
    }]
}
```

Or update your java parsing

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
channel = json.getJSONObject("channels");

// Whatever you want to do with this single channel (this is not an array)
```

Comment: If you just wrap the `channel`-content in `[]`, it's no longer valid json. You can't have a key => value in a json array and you can't have an array without a key in a json object.

Comment: Your edit doesn't actually help the OP with the issue, though. You've basically just added an extra level by wrapping the same object as the OP currently is getting, in an array.

Comment: The answer will help the OP get over the actual question of "Cannot get array from JSON using getJSONArray". I agree @MagnusEriksson answers is more appropriate to solve the whole code structure issue.

Answer (score 0):

"channels" here is a json object and not a json array.

You can do the following:

JSONObject channelsMap = json.getJSONObject("channels");

Then iterate over the "channelsMap".

For each entry in the JSONObject "channelsMap":

- key is channel name
- value is channel url